# On which chapter does Naruto married Hinata in the manga

Tags: naruto

[image]

I have watched the last episode of shippuden (marriage episode) and couldn’t find the chapter of manga. Don’t tell me that it isn’t shown in manga

Answer (score 2):

Naruto and Hinata's wedding **was never shown in the manga**. It was only depicted in the [novel](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Konoha_Hiden:_The_Perfect_Day_for_a_Wedding) titled *Konoha Hiden: The Perfect Day for a Wedding* which was written by Shō Hinata and illustrated by Masashi Kishimoto.

Comment: @Haley You're welcome. If this answers your question, you can accept it as the answer by clicking on the gray check icon beside this answer :)